# Looking for a Harry Potter fanfiction (Draco/Harry, Draco cheats, Harry pregnant)

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I have read it before. I just can't remember the name. Draco cheats on Harry with Ron and Harry finds out he is pregnant. Snape looks after him and they fall in love, then something happens where Snape becomes the biologic father of Harry's baby. Draco fights for the custody but the baby is no longer his and harry and draco were once in a relationship until he cheats on harry now its a harry and snape ending

Comment: OK, so MPreg, Drarry. And then Snape becomes part of a love triangle? Or just with one of them? Do you remember approximately when you read it? What site? Whether it was completed or was still ongoing? Approximate length? And was Harry the one who got Pregnant, or Draco?

Comment: Means, Harry also cheated on Draco with Snape. Why did Draco and Harry marry in the first place?

Comment: Are you sure this was a Harry Potter fan fic and not a Mexican soap opera!? At the end I was expecting Harry's lost evil tween brother to show up...

Comment: Human creativity has no bounds.

Comment: Related: [Harry Potter Fanfic where Harry is impregnated by Draco](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161160/harry-potter-fanfic-where-harry-is-impregnated-by-draco)

Comment: I possibly know this fic