# Harry Potter fanfic where Harry is in an abusive relationship with Draco and is later adopted by the Malfoy family

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

It is a story where the Malfoy family finds out that their son in law, Harry is being abused by Draco. Draco is later arrested and disowned. As Harry recovers, Severus’s young son helps him. During this time, Harry is adopted by the Malfoys. Along the way, Harry and Severus develop a relationship and Harry becomes pregnant.

Severus is the one who impregnated Harry. It was towards the end of the story. Most of the story is about Harrys’s recovery from the abuse he suffered because of Draco. In it Severus’s 5-9 year old son helps Harrry recover by being his friend. Also, at one point Colin Creevey kidnaps Harry. It is a Drarry that later becomes a Snarry.

I’m pretty sure I read it on adultfanfiction.com

Comment: Can you take a look at our [guide for fanfic id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11922/82909) and see what more details you can add? In particular, do you remember which site you read it on?

Comment: "Harry becomes pregnant" o.O

Comment: Possibly the same as [Looking for a Harry Potter fanfiction (Draco/Harry, Draco cheats, Harry pregnant)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/188910). Sierra, could you take a look at that question, see if it contains elements you remember as well? See also [Harry Potter Fanfic where Harry is impregnated by Draco](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/161160) (though this one seems less related)

Comment: No that’s not it. You see Severus is the one who impregnated Harry. It was towards the end of the story. Most of the story is about Harrys’s recovery from the abuse he suffered because of Draco. In it Severus’s 5-9 year old son helps Harrry recover by being his friend. Also, at one point Colin Creevey kidnaps Harry.

Comment: "at one point Colin Creevey kidnaps Harry" This is getting weirder and weirder.

Comment: It isn’t weird. It was actually a really great story. I just wish I can remember the title of it so I can read it again.

Comment: It is a drarry that later becomes a snarry.

Answer (score 2):

[*Tears and Rain*](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4165130/1/Tears-and-Rain) by [SeulWolfe](https://www.fanfiction.net/u/458513/SeulWolfe) on FanFiction.net.

***It is a story where the Malfoy family finds out that their son in law, Harry is being abused by Draco. Draco is later arrested and disowned.***

> Sadly, with each negative report, things began to go progressively downhill, and Harry began to show signs of weariness and avoided being touched. He became quiet and withdrawn, sometimes spending days in their suite, no matter how Cissa and Dobby tried to coax him out with promises of his favorite foods and pastimes. When Harry refused to see the Weasley-Grangers when they visited, Lucius had had enough, and forced his way into their suite and happened to catch Harry coming out of the bath. His blood ran cold at what he saw; the bruises that covered his son-in-law's body; everywhere except his face, hands, and belly. It certainly explained why the young man had been so withdrawn, and kept himself covered from throat to wrists, to the floor, eerily reminiscent of Severus' usual attire.
>
> That day, he had locked his son in the study with him and all but threatened him with the 'Unforgivables' if he didn't cease the mistreatment of his bonded. That behavior was no longer acceptable in the Malfoy Home, and hadn't been since Lucius and his brothers, were children. Well, tonight, they had proof that it hadn't stopped. Draco had just become more sly about it, obviously manipulating Harry further to cover it all up. Now, he and Cissa prayed that Harry would survive. Draco had disappeared to Merlin knows where, and as angry as Lucius was at the moment, it would be a wise idea if he stayed gone for several days.
>
> <sub>*Tears and Rain*, Chapter 1</sub>

***Harry becomes pregnant.***

> "I never said you were ill, Harry." Neville rocked on his heels a bit and glanced at Narcissa as his serious expression became an amused one. "What you are experiencing is perfectly normal for a wizard with your physical make-up... you're expecting."
>
> "WHAT?! I'M WHAT?!" Harry demanded, positive he'd heard Neville wrong.
>
> "Pregnant, darling. You're going to have a baby. I'm going to be a Gran'mere. Isn't it wonderful?" Narcissa was beaming.
>
> <sub>*Tears and Rain*, Chapter 32</sub>

Comment: Hello Sierra, would you mind addressing the specific points you remembered, for instance by adding some quotes? That way this becomes a more useful answer, showing other users why this is indeed correct.

Comment: I've edited in how this fan fiction matches some of the key points of your description.