# Harry Potter fanfic where Harry has amnesia and forgets his pregnant husband Draco and tries to get back together with Ginny

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

No matter how I search in google, I am unable to find this fic. Please help me if you know this fic with the details I can remember -

1. Harry and Draco are married for a long time.
2. Harry is an Auror.
3. Harry gets hit by an unknown curse and gets admitted in the hospital.
4. When he wakes up, he sees an older Hermione and Ron. They realize that Harry has amnesia.
5. Draco (who wears a Disillusionment charm to cover his pregnant body) waddles in with food into Harry's hospital room and seeing him, Harry breaks into an outrage screaming things like "What the hell is he doing here?"
6. Later, Harry is told that Malfoy is pregnant with his child and that they've been married for sometime (5-10 yrs? I don't remember)
7. Harry ignores Draco and tries to get back with Ginny (who is engaged to Dean Thomas)
8. Harry files for divorce from Draco I think?
9. Harry and Draco make an arrangement for Harry to visit their child despite their breakup.
10. Draco delivers the baby but has POSTNATAL DEPRESSION.
11. Draco leaves his baby in the care of the house elf and goes fishing for men to sate his loneliness.
12. He even accidentally apparates a dude to his bedroom and Narcissa has to obliviate the dude and send him away to his muggle world.
13. One time, a fire breaks out in the baby's nursery and Narcissa takes the baby to her place, Malfoy Manor, and tells Draco that until he cares for the child, the child would stay with her.
14. There's a scene when Draco gets badly hurt. Unable to take the pain of losing Harry he swallows 7 bottles of sleeping potion and he falls down. While falling, he hits his head on the edge of a nightstand and cuts open his head. Since he is bonded to Harry, Harry senses that something has happened to Draco and comes to their place and finds Draco almost dead.

It has a happy ending but I cannot recollect if Harry gets back his memory or not. The Healers in the fanfic do say that Harry's amnesia is permanent.

This is all I can remember. Please help me if anyone of you can find this fic.

Comment: What did I just read?!

Comment: @MorZamir - This is one of the more sensible fanfics

Comment: Let's be nice.  I mean... yea I definitely have opinions about these kinds of stories, but as questions go, this one is pretty detailed.  OP, if you can remember when you read it and from what site that would also help you get an answer.

Comment: Related
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161160/harry-potter-fanfic-where-harry-is-impregnated-by-draco

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely [La persistencia de la memoria](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5246379/1/La-persistencia-de-la-memoria) by [ScorpioPhoenix](https://www.fanfiction.net/u/1151682/ScorpioPhoenix)

> Harry loses 5 years of his memory and doesn't remember his
>   relationship with Draco. Who ended up pregnant by a strange curse.
>   Harry tries to re-live his past, as Draco fights to keep his present.
>   But will their love win in the future? Rated: Fiction M - English -
>   Angst/Romance - Harry P., Draco M. - Chapters: 10 - Words: 74,772 -
>   Reviews: 178 - Favs: 171 - Follows: 199 - Updated: Mar 23, 2010 -
>   Published: Jul 25, 2009 - id: 5246379

1. Harry and Draco are married for a long time.

> "Harry," he said, "you don't remember me?" Harry snorted. "Of course I
>   remember you. I've been calling you Malfoy, haven't I? What I don't
>   remember is why the hell you would be in my room." "We're together,
>   Harry. Friends, you know. It's been like that for a while."

2. Harry is an Auror.

> Harry blinked and tried to focus on himself. "I'm an Auror…I know
>   that. I've been one for…four years....

.

> Hermione was shaking her head sadly. "None of that is right, Harry.
>   You've been an Auror for nine years now.

3. Harry gets hit by an unknown curse and gets admitted in the hospital.

> Ron grinned. "Another Blasting Curse, my friend. You've been out cold
>   for two days." Harry sighed heavily. "Great, just what I needed. How
>   much damage this time?" "Broken ribs, nasty wallop on the head,
>   fractured leg…" Ron provided helpfully. Hermione stepped forward,
>   looking eager. "We were so worried, Harry. You've never been out this
>   long. The healers were especially worried about that bump. It was a
>   concussion.

4. When he wakes up, he sees an older Hermione and Ron. They realize that Harry has amnesia.

> Now Ron looked over at Harry with concern. "We've been married three
>   years, Mate. You were best man!" "Three years?? I-I don't remember
>   that at all!" He turned panic-stricken towards Wilde. "What's happened
>   to me? Why can't I remember that?" "Mister Potter, calm down. I just
>   need you to tell me what you do remember."

5. Draco (who wears a Disillusionment charm to cover his pregnant body) waddles in with food into Harry's hospital room and seeing him, Harry breaks into an outrage screaming things like "What the hell is he doing here?"

> The door to the room opened and a head of blond hair poked around the
>   corner. Ron rubbed his hands together. "Bout time you got back,
>   Malfoy. I'm starving." Draco walked through the door holding a brown
>   bag that was emanating delicious odors. "Next time you get the food
>   then," he retorted and proceeded to put the bag down. Ron strolled
>   over quickly to dive into its contents.

(There's no mention of disllusionment charm)

> "What the hell is he doing here?" Harry rasped out, "and bringing
>   take-out?" All three turned to stare at Harry. Hermione glanced at
>   Draco anxiously and then back to Harry. "What do you mean?" "I mean,
>   why is Malfoy here in my room? Bringing food? Like you're all friends
>   or something?" Draco frowned and then said, "Because we are friends.
>   Well…sort of. I still think Weasley here is a pig, but…" Harry
>   narrowed his eyes and Draco shut his mouth. "Get out, Malfoy!"

6. Later, Harry is told that Malfoy is pregnant with his child and that they've been married for sometime (5-10 yrs? I don't remember)

> "We're together, Harry. Friends, you know. It's been like that for a
>   while." Harry stared incredulously at Draco and then looked at
>   Hermione. "Huh?" Hermione nodded encouragingly. "Yes, it's true. You
>   and Draco are…friends. Close…friends," she added.

(Doesn't say anything about married, just says close friends. And doesn't say anything about how long, but he broke up with Ginny 5 years ago, so, 5 years?)

> Hermione was shaking her head sadly. "None of that is right, Harry.
>   You've been an Auror for nine years now. You don't live at Grimmauld
>   anymore, Ron and I do. And you and Ginny broke up…five years ago."

7. Harry ignores Draco and tries to get back with Ginny (who is engaged to Dean Thomas)

> "Ron, I want to see Ginny. Where is she?" Ron made a face and
>   scratched the back of his neck. "Well…about that. You and Ginny broke
>   up." "Okay…but we can work things out. Maybe start over." Ron
>   shrugged. "As much as I would love for you and Ginny to get back
>   together…there's a slight problem." "And that is?" "She's engaged to
>   Dean Thomas." "Well…maybe I can still talk to her."

8. Harry files for divorce from Draco I think?
   (can't find this but I don't think they are officially married)
9. Harry and Draco make an arrangement for Harry to visit their child despite their breakup.
   (can't find this but there are places where Harry talks about being there for the child but not as a father (Draco is enraged by this idea) )
10. Draco delivers the baby but has POSTNATAL DEPRESSION.

> Harry, on the other hand, had connected with Cassi beautifully, and
>   Narcissa knew this probably was because of Teddy, who Harry had
>   brought on one of his visits. Draco had been in St. Mungo's for three
>   days after the birth, and then had released him two days ago. Narcissa
>   had wanted Draco to come to the manor, not just because of Draco
>   obviously needing help with the new baby, but also because of Draco's
>   melancholy. His depression had worsened in the last few days and
>   Harry's presence with Cassi wasn't helping very much. She could see
>   the longing in her son's eyes.

11. Draco leaves his baby in the care of the house elf and goes fishing for men to sate his loneliness.

> Draco stormed out of the floo and flounced into living room. He tore
>   off his robes and threw them onto the couch. Cassi was crying again
>   and Draco had had it with her whining "Tippy!" Draco shouted. The elf
>   popped up on command. "Yes, Master Draco?" "Watch the baby." He then
>   apparated before Tippy could get a word in edgewise.

.

> "You look like you're in need of a friend," blue eyes said, glancing
>   at Draco's bottle. "Tough day?" Draco fiddled with his glass and then
>   looked at the handsome man. "No, I don't need a friend." Blue eyes
>   looked disappointed and then shrugged. "Sorry to have bothered you
>   then." He stood up to walk away, but Draco reached out and grabbed his
>   arm. "No, I don't need a friend…but I do need a good fuck." Blue eyes
>   lit up with a smile.

12. He even accidentally apparates a dude to his bedroom ...
    (This part is in [chapter 5](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5246379/5/La-persistencia-de-la-memoria), i suggest you look for it yourself)

... and Narcissa has to obliviate the dude and send him away to his muggle world.

> She then pointed it at Tank-man. "Ennervate!" The man gave a low groan
>   and tried to sit up. Narcissa pointed the wand at him again.
>   "Obliviate!" She turned and handed the wand back to Draco. "I help my
>   family. That's something else the Malfoy's do."

13. One time, a fire breaks out in the baby's nursery and Narcissa takes the baby to her place, Malfoy Manor, and tells Draco that until he cares for the child, the child would stay with her.

> When Draco arrived back into his bedroom, he stared at the damaged
>   wall and carpet. The fire hadn't spread too far, but if his mother
>   hadn't come, then he could've died. And Cassiopeia. Harry would never
>   have forgiven him if something had happened to the baby. But as he
>   thought about it, he knew he didn't want her to die either. The baby
>   was helpless and Draco would never forgive himself either if she had
>   been seriously injured under his watch. Maybe this was for the best,
>   his mother taking Cassiopeia. She had always wanted a daughter, so now
>   she had one. Sort of. Draco was in no shape to take care of an infant,
>   that much was abundantly clear.

14. There's a scene when Draco gets badly hurt. Unable to take the pain of losing Harry he swallows 7 bottles of sleeping potion and he falls down. While falling, he hits his head on the edge of a nightstand and cuts open his head. Since he is bonded to Harry, Harry senses that something has happened to Draco and comes to their place and finds Draco almost dead.

> He pulled the drawer open and saw several vials of the Dreamless
>   Sleep potion. Draco didn't want to think, he didn't want to feel. He
>   just wanted oblivion. His hand shook as he opened three of the vials
>   and downed them. When he didn't feel the effects right away, he downed
>   the remaining vials. Seven in all. The effect was immediate after
>   that. Draco didn't make it to the bed, but collapsed on the floor in
>   front of the nightstand. As he fell, he hit his head on the front of
>   the stand and his  head split in a vicious, jagged cut. The blood
>   spurted from the wound and began to pool on the carpet, ruining it.

.

> Harry gave a loud gasp and Hermione turned around. "What's wrong?"
>   Harry was standing absolutely still, as if he was listening for
>   something. He then raised a hand to his chest and patted it violently.
>   "Something's wrong with Draco. I can feel it."

.

> "Malfoy? Malfoy!" Harry called as he shook the blond. "Can you hear
>   me?" Draco didn't move and Harry swore. He gently turned the man over
>   on his back and Harry winced at the nasty gash across the top of his
>   head. Harry pulled his wand and cast a healing charm over the wound.
>   He watched as the edges resealed themselves and the flow of blood
>   stopped. As an auror, Harry was required to know several rudimentary
>   healing spells as part of his work.

Comment: I can't find the bit about the happy ending or if Harry got his memory back, but I just can't read this any more. Someone read the full story and edit in/add a new answer please.